# Mimekit/mailkit download message body?

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

I have been making my own mail client recently and added a receive option, I used mimekit and mailkit as plugins and was able to download most of my mails with a reader that is supposed to show content(right now it shows subject, to, from, date)

The way I downloaded the subject, to, ... is msg.envelope.subject, msg.envelope.to
But I cannot download the body like this :( when doing either msg.body, msg.textbody, msg.bodyparts, ... they all result in NOTHING, the place where it should be is just empty, I can't get it downloaded :(

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 ways to get the message body:

**1. Download the Whole Message**

This method is probably the easiest way.

To do this, all you need to do is call:

```
var message = folder.GetMessage (uid);
```

or

```
var message = folder.GetMessage (index);
```

I would recommend always using the `UniqueId` of the message. Since you are already using the `Fetch` method, all you need to do to make sure that you have the `UniqueId` of the message is to include the `MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId` in your fetch request:

```
var messages = folder.Fetch (0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId |
    MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | ...);
```

Once you have the message, you can do whatever you want with it.

For rendering the message, I would recommend taking a look at the `MessageReader` sample included in the [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) GitHub repository.

It will show you how to properly render a `MimeMessage`.

**2. Download Only What You Need**

This method is a bit harder but *can* be more efficient as far as network bandwidth usage goes.

The first thing you need to do is to make sure to include the `MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure` bit flag in the `Fetch` method. For example:

```
var messages = folder.Fetch (0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | 
    MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);
```

(You'll probably want other fields, but that's just an example to show you how to bitwise-or flags together to request multiple message summary items).

By requesting the `BodyStructure` of the messages, you'll be able to make use of the `msg.Body` property.

Each `msg.Body` will be a `BodyPart` object which is an abstract class. The 2 main subclasses are `BodyPartMultipart` and `BodyPartBasic`. You can use the `as` cast or the `is` keyword to figure out which one it is:

```
var multipart = msg.Body as BodyPartMultipart;

if (multipart != null) {
    // the top-level body part is a multi-part
} else {
    // the body is a basic singleton part
}
```

This is how you would iterate over the subparts of a `BodyPartMultipart`:

```
foreach (var part in multipart.BodyParts) {
    // each part will either be a BodyPartMultipart
    // or a BodyPartBasic, just like before...
}
```

There are also 2 subclasses of `BodyPartBasic` which are: `BodyPartText` and `BodyPartMessage`. A `BodyPartText` is a textual-based MIME part (meaning it has a MIME-type of `text/*`) whereas a `BodyPartMessage` is an embedded message (and will have a MIME-type of `message/rfc822`).

Since MIME is recursive, you'll need to implement a recursive function to walk the MIME tree structure to find whatever MIME part you are looking for.

For your convenience, the `TextBody` and `HtmlBody` properties on the `IMessageSummary` interface will locate and return the `text/plain` and `text/html` body parts, respectively.

It should be noted, however, that these properties only work in cases where the structure of the message follows the standard convention (notice I said *convention*, there is no formal standard dictating the location of the message text within a MIME hierarchy).

It should also be noted that if your mail client will be rendering the HTML body, the HTML body part may be part of a group of related MIME parts (i.e. a child of a `multipart/related`), but the `HtmlBody` property will not be able to return that and so implementing your own recursive logic will be a better option.

For an example of how to do this, check out the `ImapClientDemo` sample in the [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) GitHub repository. The logic currently resides in the MainWindow.cs code.

Comment: Thanks but I have one question, on the mimekit documentation it keeps referring to "stream" (e.g. var message = MimeMessage.Load (STREAM);) I have no idea where this is coming from, I tried creating a memory stream but it threw an exception: value cannot be null

Comment: Well, the Load() method parses a stream... so if you are passing in an empty stream, then it can't parse it, can it? If you are actually writing content into the stream before passing it to the Load() method, make sure to seek back to the beginning of the stream.

Comment: BTW, the stream can be from `File.OpenRead()` or `new FileStream()` and that's generally what they'll be from.

Comment: Is there just a simple sample code which can be reused to download and extract the html and text body parts without downloading the attachments? the MailKit GitHub sample code isn't very intuitive

Comment: Read my answer above, it answers your question: `For your convenience, the TextBody and HtmlBody properties on the IMessageSummary interface will locate and return the text/plain and text/html body parts, respectively.`

Comment: Once you have the `BodyPart`, all you need to do is call one of these `GetBodyPart()` overloads: http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MailKit_Net_Imap_ImapFolder_GetBodyPart.htm